# Animate Noise Texture W through Simulation Zone

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, animation-nodes, displacement, simulation-nodes

I'm currently testing the Simulation Zone in Geometry Nodes and wanted to animate just the W value of the noise texture through it. My current setup is just displacing the mesh, and the Simulation Zone keeps adding up the same value, which I expected, but I want it to react as if I animated the w value instead. My goal is to have control over those keyframes so I can cache them in RAM with the Simulation Zone.[image: This is the setup]

Comment: There is no need in simulation zone in this setup